# Php flip the echo result

Tags: php, mysqli

I confused the method to flip the place of the echo result, below is my code

```
while ($looptools == 0) {
    $mysqlihelper = " SELECT * FROM soal WHERE nomorsoal = $numberofmysqli ";
    $mysqliquery = mysqli_query($konek, $mysqlihelper);
    $resultquery = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mysqliquery);
    $resulttextjudul = $resultquery['judul'];
    if ($resulttextjudul == null) {
        unset($resulttextjudul);
        $resulttextjudul = "Tunggu Soal Berikutnya ! ..";
        $nullerror = true;
    } else {
    }
    if ($nullerror == true) {
        echo "<div class=\"head-main-recenttest-result\" style=\"text-decoration:none\">" . $resulttextjudul . "</div>";
    } else {
        echo "<a href=\"bacasoal.php\"><div class=\"head-main-recenttest-result\"  style=\"text-decoration:none\">" . $resulttextjudul . "</div></a>";
    }
    if ($nullerror == true) {
        mysqli_close($konek);
        break;
    } elseif ($looptools == 10) {
        mysqli_close($konek);
        break;
    } else {
    }
}
```

As you see in the "`while`", it's echo the first result and the second result below it, but I want the first result in below of the second result, can anyone tell me the method to do it?

Comment: So why don't you add an `ORDER BY` in the query?

Comment: that's still make the first result above the second result

Comment: Yes, but the results are reversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry if i answer my own question because i found it out myself

use mysqli_num_rows or often called mysqli count

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean you want to print all successes followed by all errors, or something like that.  Here's how:

```
if($nullerror == true){
    $errors .= "<div class=\"head-main-recenttest-result\" style=\"text-decoration:none\">".$resulttextjudul."</div>";
 }else{
    $successes .= "<a href=\"bacasoal.php\"><div class=\"head-main-recenttest-result\"  style=\"text-decoration:none\">".$resulttextjudul."</div></a>";
 }
```

Then, when the while loop is done:

```
echo $successes ; 
echo $errors ;
```

If you really want to work your way backwards through the results in `$mysqliquery`, that's a different answer.

UPDATE: to reverse the order of successes / errors on display, just put the latest additions in front:

```
if($nullerror == true){
    $errors = "<div class=\"head-main-recenttest-result\" style=\"text-decoration:none\">".$resulttextjudul."</div>" . $errors;
 }else{
    $successes = "<a href=\"bacasoal.php\"><div class=\"head-main-recenttest-result\"  style=\"text-decoration:none\">".$resulttextjudul."</div></a>" . $successes ;
 }
```

Comment: how about flip the place of the first success with the second success ?

Comment: the error only appear if there's no more success , and how about if there's about 3 success ? like number 1 , 2 , 3 , but i want to echo them 3 , 2 , 1

Comment: OH I FOUND OUT HOW